# More Precise Question Titles and Tags

Tags: discussion, titles

One of my aims in editing is detailing titles to help users pinpoint the germane post. Are there any stopgaps for muzzy titles?

For example, a search for "help" yields $> 38,000$ questions which includes titles in the manner of "Help with Proof", "Help with Definition", "Help with Integration," ...

I read [Editing title results in unwanted "bump" ...](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/editing-title-results-in-unwanted-bump), [Suggesting more specific titles to an OP](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/suggesting-more-specific-titles-to-an-op), [On question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10594/on-question-titles).

Comment: Related: [Retitling Questions: a modest proposal](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8756)

Comment: [These titles](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=title%3ahelp) definitely need help...

Comment: @draks... Though I especially liked "Q: Asymptotic help" Seems we are not supposed to give an immediate solution but only should add better and better answers over time :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: No, it means that we should have a tendency to help that question . . .

Comment: We radically and supremely forgive you.